# Blob Storage Azure Mobile Services + Swift Setup

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-blob-storage

Unfortunately, there is not much documentation on Microsoft's Azure Blob Storage for Mobile Services (let alone a functional [SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/01/help-us-shape-the-azure-storage-ios-library.aspx)).

I've already set up a container on the Azure Storage Service, and I'm trying to configure blob storage on Swift through the mobile service.

What is the best way to go about doing this, and how should I go about configuring this for iOS Swift?

Comment: I think the best way to solve the issue is to visit this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/01/help-us-shape-the-azure-storage-ios-library.aspx Clearly Microsoft has some documentation on Blob Storage REST API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx Which version iOS or dank are you on? Are you developing blob access for an existing app, or a new one?